# Are there any functions like getattr/hasattr but which skip instance attributes?

Tags: python, attributes, idioms, standard-library, class-variables

Are there any functions like the built-in functions [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) in the standard library but which *skip instance attributes* during attribute lookup, like the [implicit lookup of special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup)?

Let’s call these hypothetical functions `getclassattr` and `hasclassattr`. Here are the implementations that I would expect:

```py
null = object()

def getclassattr(obj, name, default=null, /):
    if not isinstance(name, str):
        raise TypeError('getclassattr(): attribute name must be string')
    try:
        classmro = vars(type)['__mro__'].__get__(type(obj))
        for cls in classmro:
            classdict = vars(type)['__dict__'].__get__(cls)
            if name in classdict:
                attr = classdict[name]
                attrclassmro = vars(type)['__mro__'].__get__(type(attr))
                for attrclass in attrclassmro:
                    attrclassdict = vars(type)['__dict__'].__get__(attrclass)
                    if '__get__' in attrclassdict:
                        return attrclassdict['__get__'](attr, obj, type(obj))
                return attr
        classname = vars(type)['__name__'].__get__(type(obj))
        raise AttributeError(f'{classname!r} object has no attribute {name!r}')
    except AttributeError as exc:
        try:
            classmro = vars(type)['__mro__'].__get__(type(obj))
            for cls in classmro:
                classdict = vars(type)['__dict__'].__get__(cls)
                if '__getattr__' in classdict:
                    return classdict['__getattr__'](obj, name)
        except AttributeError as exc_2:
            exc = exc_2
        except BaseException as exc_2:
            raise exc_2 from None
        if default is not null:
            return default
        raise exc from None
```

```py
def hasclassattr(obj, name, /):
    try:
        getclassattr(obj, name)
    except AttributeError:
        return False
    return True
```

A use case is a pure Python implementation of the built-in class [`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) in which the hypothetical functions `getclassattr` and `hasclassattr` look up the attribute `'__get__'` on the class `type(self.__func__)`:*

```py
import types

class ClassMethod:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.__func__ = function

    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None and owner is None:
            raise TypeError('__get__(None, None) is invalid')
        if owner is None:
            owner = type(instance)
        # Note that we use hasclassattr here, not hasattr.
        if hasclassattr(self.__func__, '__get__'):
            # Note that we use getclassattr here, not getattr.
            return getclassattr(self.__func__, '__get__')(owner, type(owner))
        return types.MethodType(self.__func__, owner)

    @property
    def __isabstractmethod__(self):
        return hasattr(self.__func__, '__isabstractmethod__')

class M(type):
    pass

class C(metaclass=M):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        pass

assert ClassMethod(C).__get__(123) == classmethod(C).__get__(123)
```

---

* Note that calling the hypothetical functions `getclassattr` and `hasclassattr` on `self.__func__` instead of calling the built-in functions `getattr` and `hasattr` on it does not work since they look up the attribute `'__get__'` both on the instance `self.__func__` and on the class `type(self.__func__)`:

```py
import types

class ClassMethod:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.__func__ = function
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None and owner is None:
            raise TypeError('__get__(None, None) is invalid')
        if owner is None:
            owner = type(instance)
        if hasattr(self.__func__, '__get__'):
            return getattr(self.__func__, '__get__')(owner, type(owner))
        return types.MethodType(self.__func__, owner)
    @property
    def __isabstractmethod__(self):
        return hasattr(self.__func__, '__isabstractmethod__')

class M(type):
    pass

class C(metaclass=M):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        pass

assert ClassMethod(C).__get__(123) != classmethod(C).__get__(123)
```

Calling the built-in functions `getattr` and `hasattr` on `type(self.__func__)` does not work either since they look up the attribute `'__get__'` both on the instance `type(self.__func__)` and on the class `type(type(self.__func__))`:

```py
import types

class ClassMethod:
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.__func__ = function
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None and owner is None:
            raise TypeError('__get__(None, None) is invalid')
        if owner is None:
            owner = type(instance)
        if hasattr(type(self.__func__), '__get__'):
            return getattr(type(self.__func__), '__get__')(owner, type(owner))
        return types.MethodType(self.__func__, owner)
    @property
    def __isabstractmethod__(self):
        return hasattr(self.__func__, '__isabstractmethod__')

class MM(type):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        pass

class M(type, metaclass=MM):
    pass

class C(metaclass=M):
    pass

assert ClassMethod(C).__get__(123) != classmethod(C).__get__(123)
```

Comment: Why not just... use `getattr` or `hasattr` on the class, instead of on the instance?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: That causes problems with metaclasses and descriptors.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Because this would also look up the attribute on the metaclass, so `ClassMethod(a).__get__(3)` would return `'metaclass'` (not `'class'`) in the last code snippet.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand the problem. Could you show an example of the `getclassattr` implementation *directly* doing something different from the built-in `getattr` applied to the class?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Yes: `class A: x = 'foo'; a = A(); a.x = 'bar'; print(getattr(a, 'x')); print(getclassattr(a, 'x'))` prints `bar\nfoo`.

Comment: No, I said to apply `getattr` to the *class*. Like `getattr(a.__class__, 'x')`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Sorry I misunderstood: `class M(type): x = 'bar'`, `class A(metaclass=M): x = 'foo'`, `print(getattr(A, 'x'))`, `print(getclassattr(A, 'x'))` prints `foo\nbar`.

Comment: Ah, so you don't only want to "skip the instance dictionary" but also explicitly *prioritize* the metaclass dictionary, which normally doesn't happen for *either* an instance or class lookup (although, it is consulted for class lookups if not otherwise found)... ?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel A class is a metaclass instance so there is no special metaclass handling here, we just skip the (metaclass) instance dictionary like usual.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231178/discussion-between-karl-knechtel-and-maggyero).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Do you have any idea of what ‘advanced usages’ Guido is referring to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67425120/2326961)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of introducing new functions `getclassattr` and `hasclassattr` to skip instance attributes during attribute lookup, like the [implicit lookup of special methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-lookup), an alternative approach is to introduce a proxy class (let’s call it `skip`) that overrides the method `__getattribute__`. I think it is a better approach since the method `__getattribute__` is a hook designed for customising attribute lookup, and it works with the built-in functions `getattr` and `hasattr` but also with the attribute retrieval operator `.`:

```py
class skip:
    def __init__(self, subject):
        self.subject = subject

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        obj = super().__getattribute__('subject')
        classmro = vars(type)['__mro__'].__get__(type(obj))
        for cls in classmro:
            classdict = vars(type)['__dict__'].__get__(cls)
            if name in classdict:
                attr = classdict[name]
                attrclassmro = vars(type)['__mro__'].__get__(type(attr))
                for attrclass in attrclassmro:
                    attrclassdict = vars(type)['__dict__'].__get__(attrclass)
                    if '__get__' in attrclassdict:
                        return attrclassdict['__get__'](attr, obj, type(obj))
                return attr
        classname = vars(type)['__name__'].__get__(type(obj))
        raise AttributeError(
            f'{classname!r} object has no attribute {name!r}')

class M(type):
    x = 'metaclass'

class A(metaclass=M):
    x = 'class'

a = A()
a.x = 'object'
assert getattr(a, 'x') == 'object'
assert getattr(skip(a), 'x') == 'class'
assert getattr(A, 'x') == 'class'
assert getattr(skip(A), 'x') == 'metaclass'
```