# How should callables retrieved with super() be called?

Tags: python, function, methods, super

I noticed that with this `B.f` implementation, the call `B.f(B)` raises a `TypeError`:

```py
>>> class A:
...     def f(self): print('foo')
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def f(self):
...         super().f()
...         print('bar')
... 
>>> B.f(B())  # instance self argument
foo
bar
>>> B.f(B)    # non-instance self argument
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

But with this `B.f` implementation, the call `B.f(B)` works:

```py
>>> class A:
...     def f(self): print('foo')
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def f(self):
...         if isinstance(self, B): super().f()  # bound method call
...         else: super().f(self)                # function call
...         print('bar')
... 
>>> B.f(B())  # instance self argument
foo
bar
>>> B.f(B)    # non-instance self argument
foo
bar
```

This is because `super().f` (i.e. `super(B, self).f`) retrieves the *bound method* `types.MethodType(A.f, self)` when `self` is an instance of `B`, and retrieves the *function* `A.f` otherwise:

```py
>>> super(B, B()).f
<bound method A.f of <__main__.B object at 0x10e6bda90>>
>>> super(B, B).f
<function A.f at 0x10e7d6790>
```

So I wonder which of the two `B.f` implementations above is idiomatic. In other words, should a class designer assume that the functions of the class will always be called with a `self` argument that is an instance of the class (like the first `B.f` implementation which always calls `super().f` as a bound method, i.e. `super().f()`), or should he also handle the situation where the `self` argument is not an instance of the class* (like the second `B.f` implementation which calls `super().f` as a bound method, i.e. `super().f()`, *or* as a function, i.e. `super().f(self)`)?

---

* This is possible since Python 3.0 to allow advanced usages, as Guido van Rossum [explained](https://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/first-class-everything.html):

> In Python 3000, the concept of unbound methods has been removed, and the expression "A.spam" returns a plain function object. It turned out that the restriction that the first argument had to be an instance of A was rarely helpful in diagnosing problems, and frequently an obstacle to advanced usages --- some have called it "duck typing self" which seems an appropriate name.

Comment: As I state in my answer on the second link: The one-argument form of `super()` doesn’t work important corner cases, was designed in a Python 2 world and obsolete. Guido agreed it should be considered deprecated. Using that form is not idiomatic.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think there is a confusion. This post is actually not about the one-argument form of `super()` at all (it is not even specific to `super()`, cf. [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67425120/2326961) below). It is about the applications of duck typing `self` that Guido is referring to (`self` understood as the first argument of a method of a class, not the second argument of the built-in function `super()`—I think this is where you were confused).

Comment: @MartijnPieters So since it is not a duplicate, unless I am mistaken, could we reopen the question?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have opened a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67541511/2326961) about yet another way that method calls can fail.

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering which of the two B.f implementations above is idiomatic

The simpler one is idiomatic.

I can't really see a good reason why a subclass would do `isinstance(self, Subclass)` at all, or why a caller would want to do `B.f(B)`.

Comment: Like you, I wonder what are these ‘advanced usages’ that Guido is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, there are instance methods (which tend to have `self` as the first argument, and no decorator), static methods (which have the `@staticmethod` decorator), and class methods (which have the `@classmethod` decorator). You will see these two decorators (staticmethod, classmethod) are listed as [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

When you call `B().f()`, since `B()` is an instance, there is an implicit transformation of the method into a function whose first argument is the instance, which [is described in the docs here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods).

When you call `B.f()`, on the other hand, this does not happen; no extra argument values are inserted (the [same docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/howto/descriptor.html#static-methods-and-class-methods) explain this as well). However, since the method `f` is defined with one argument that has no default value, that is where the error "missing 1 required positional argument..." comes in.

As for code conventions, you *can* add `isinstance` checks but oftentimes, the code will assume that the user will call the method with the correct types or from an instance of the correct type, if necessary; otherwise the user will encounter an error. This way, your code can remain simple.

```py
b = B()
# The `self` identifier inside `B.f` will be identical in the following two calls
b.f()
B.f(b)  # Would not expect users to call `f` this way unless marked as static

# The `self` identifier in `B.f` below is a class rather than an instance of the class, as in the above two cases
# Typically, you would _not_ expect users to call `f` this way.
B.f(B)
```

Comment: I wonder what are these ‘advanced usages’ Guido that is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

I have just realised with this `A.g` implementation that the issue is not specific to using `super()`:

```py
>>> class A:
...     def f(self): print('foo')
...     def g(self):
...         self.f()
...         print('bar')
... 
>>> A.g(A())
foo
bar
>>> A.g(A)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in g
TypeError: f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

We typically don’t write this `A.g` implementation:

```py
>>> class A:
...     def f(self): print('foo')
...     def g(self):
...         if isinstance(self, A): self.f()  # bound method call
...         else: self.f(self)                # function call
...         print('bar')
... 
>>> A.g(A())
foo
bar
>>> A.g(A)
foo
bar
```

But should we? I wonder what are these ‘advanced usages’ of non-instance first arguments that Guido van Rossum is referring to.