# Is it a bad practice to override a method of a class in an instance?

Tags: python, overriding, instance, method-call

Let’s say that I write a metaclass `M` and a user writes an instance `A` of my metaclass which overrides a method `g`:

```py
>>> class M(type):
...     def f(self): return self.g()
...     def g(self): return 'foo'
... 
>>> class A(metaclass=M):
...     def g(self): return 'bar'
... 
>>> A.f()  # oops!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
TypeError: g() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
>>> del A.g
>>> A.f()
'foo'
```

Or let’s say that I write a class `A` and a user writes an instance `a` of my class which overrides a method `g`:

```py
>>> class A:
...     def f(self): return self.g()
...     def g(self): return 'foo'
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.g = lambda self: 'bar'
>>> a.f()  # oops!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
>>> del a.g
>>> a.f()
'foo'
```

Is it a bad practice to override a method of a class in an instance?

Comment: Certainly not with an implementation that doesn't work. Otherwise it depends on the context.

Comment: Monkey-patching like your (attempted) redefinition/overwriting of `a.g` is definitely not to be done casually - tracking this sort of thing down is a nightmare for maintenance. If it needs doing a specialised class inheriting from A would be a much more maintainable and understandable approach.

Comment: What you are describing is monkey-patching. It is generally not considered a great thing. Usually, it is used as a method of last resort.

Comment: @barny And what about the `A.g`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only valid answer here is the same as the old chestnut response the doctor gives when you ask what to do about the pain you feel when you jab yourself in the eye repeatedly: **If it hurts, stop doing that**. Your eye was not designed to have a finger jabbed in it.

So, *yes*, it is bad practice to add a method to an instance or a class *when it breaks the expectations of the existing code that calls it*.

Note that this has really nothing to do with the specifics of your examples. **Any** existing code can be broken this way, by replacing or shadowing something else with an implementation that doesn't fit the existing expectations.

Your examples can be trivially fixed; to replace the `M.g` method on a class, use a class method. To replace `A.g` on the instance, use a function that doesn't expect `self`. Both would fit the expectations of the existing code: that calling `g` does not require additional arguments.

Python is highly dynamic, and that gives you loads and loads of freedom, including the freedom to poke yourself in the proverbial eye. Try not to do that last thing or anything else that could hurt your code, and you should be fine.

Comment: ‘Both would fit the expectations of the existing code: that calling `g` does not require additional arguments.’ Thanks, that is exactly the expectations that I was looking for. But these are expectations of the *implementation* of `M`, not of its *interface*. So isn’t it a problem if a user of my class `M` has to rely on `M`’s implementation instead of just `M`’s interface in order to use it? It seems to violate the first principle of object-oriented design: *Program to an interface, not an implementation.*

Comment: In other words, Python’s dynamic nature allows introducing implementation dependencies like the dependency of `A` on `M`’s implementation. So shouldn’t we conclude instead that it is a bad practice *in general* to override a method of a class in an instance, i.e. one should *never* do it?

Comment: It is not the implementation of `M` that you are relying on. `M` expects `A.g()` to exist and work, you gave it `A.g(self)`. Your second example expects `a.g()` to work, but you gave it `a.g(self)` instead. In both cases it is **your implementation** that breaks those expectations.

Comment: Don't conflate a misunderstanding of how binding works in these cases with implementation dependencies. You have confused implementation details (that in the first case, `A.g()` happens to be a metaclass method, and `a.g()` happens to be a method implemented on `A`) with a specific dependency on those implementations. Nowhere in `M.f()` or `A.f()` is there a dependency on how `g` is implemented.

Comment: So, no, there is no such conclusion to be drawn here, not even close. There is **tonnes** of code, good code, that overrides methods via instance attributes, in the standard library and elsewhere. Take a look at how [`IPv4Network.hosts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network.hosts) works for one such example, if you are curious.

Comment: ‘`M` expects `A.g()` to exist and work’ Yes, but how do we know it? I expect that the users of my metaclass `M` don’t have to look at its *implementation*. They should derive it only from its *interface*. Let’s try: `M` has two instance methods `f` and `g` (they bind to an instance of `M`). To override them in an instance (a class, like `A`), we must keep the same signatures (a first parameter instance of `M`) so class methods since they will bind to the instance. Okay that works.

Comment: ‘Your second example expects `a.g()` to work’ Yes, but how do we know it? Let’s try: `A` has two instance methods `f` and `g` (they bind to an instance of `A`). To override them in an instance (a non-class, like `a`), we must keep the same signatures (a first parameter instance of `A`) so class methods since we are in an instance. But since the instance is not a class this time, the class method will not bind to the instance so it will not work. So the only solution to simulate a bound method is to remove the first argument from the signature as you suggested.

Comment: The bottom line: overriding a method of a class in an instance is not a bad practice as long as we respect the *interface* of the class. This seems to be what you meant, so answer accepted. Thanks Martijn!

Answer (score 2):

The rare cases in which monkey-patching has to be used as a last resort tend to be cases where you don't have access to the source code to implement a proper solution, or where you're somehow unable to define a subclass of the class you're hoping to fix or extend.

It's a bad practice in most other cases and often a final resort in a codebase that has become burdened with too many bad design decisions, when it's not trying to fix a third party solution for which you don't have the code.